# I closed Terminal while working on my rails app

Tags: command-line, terminal

So I closed terminal and my server went down. How do I reconnect Terminal to the file I was working on in Sublime and get the server back up?
Thanks for the help.

Answer (score 0):

> closed terminal and my server went down

You can't. Unless your editor save any sort of backup files from time to time (or keeps temporary recoverable data like) or you saved your file before served shut down.